# How to query cross catalog tables (e.g, joint tables from mysql and hive) from Apache Superset to PrestoDB?

Tags: presto, apache-superset

How to query cross catalog tables (e.g, joint tables from mysql and hive) from Apache Superset to PrestoDB? What's the SQLAlchemy URI should be enter in Superset?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Superset is just a UI tool that uses SQLAlchemy to hit Presto. So if you want to have a join across mysql and hive you need to do the following :

- Make sure Presto has access to both MySQL and Hive.

  For MySQL : 
  https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/mysql.html

  Hive : 
  https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive.html
- Add Presto itself to Superset
- Write your query across different datasource by using the catalog

For example :

```
SELECT *
FROM mysql.mydb.mytable a JOIN hive.mydb.mytable b
ON a.id = b.id
```

This way, presto will fetch the data from both sources, get your the result.

So in nutshell, you need presto://host:port, that is it :)